# Django IntegryError Response does not work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am writing a rest api where users are able to register, login and add keyword. But the keyword will only be added if they equals to one of the AllowedKeyword Model. I have done all so far, but i have to catch the IntegrityError if the combination of keyword and owner already exists.

But if i try a api call it response the keyword i wanted to add (but he does not save it, which is correct) instead of Response the error.

Here is the relevant code:

apy.py

```
class KeywordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.keywords.all()

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    try:
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        return Response({
            "IntegrityError": "This combination already exists."
        })
```

serializers.py

```
def allow_keyword(key):

if AllowedKeyword.objects.filter(allowed_keyword=key).exists():
    return key
else:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('This Keyword ist not allowed')


class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #keyword = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    keyword = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[allow_keyword])

    class Meta:
        model = Keyword
        fields = ('id', 'keyword', )
```

models.py

```
class AllowedKeyword(models.Model):
    allowed_keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.allowed_keyword)


class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='keywords')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.keyword)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('keyword', 'owner')
```

Output if keyword is not in AllowedKeyword
{
    "keyword": [
        "This Keyword ist not allowed"
    ]
}

Output if keyword is unique and in AllowedKeyword
{
    "id": 11,
    "keyword": "bitcoin"
}

Outout if keyword already exists in Keyword and is in AllowedKeyword
{
    "keyword": "bitcoin"
}

=> But should be the Response after catching the IntegrityError

I hope you guys could help me
Cheers

**EDIT**

if i use raise ValidationError instead of Response it works, but i want this error in json

**EDIT 2**
For more information, if i dont catch the error i get this

IntegrityError at /api/keywords/
UNIQUE constraint failed: news_keyword.keyword, news_keyword.owner_id

I just want to catch this error and response a json response

Comment: two owner on keyword models?

Comment: @HemanthSP what do you mean? There is a list of allowed keywords, one user can have x keywords if this keywords is equal to one of the allowed keywords.

Comment: ahh i see the other should be commented

Comment: @HemanthSP still the same result

Comment: try this res = { "message": "ypur msg"} return Response(data=json.dumps(res),status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Comment: @HemanthSP still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a idea and now i tried another way. I implemented the validate method in the serializer and now it works fine

```
class KeywordViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.keywords.all()

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)


def allow_keyword(key):

if AllowedKeyword.objects.filter(allowed_keyword=key).exists():
    return key
else:
    raise serializers.ValidationError('This Keyword is not allowed')
```

.

```
class KeywordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
keyword = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[allow_keyword])

class Meta:
    model = Keyword
    fields = ('id', 'keyword', )

def validate(self, data):
    if Keyword.objects.filter(keyword=data['keyword'], owner=self.context['request'].user).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("combination exists")
    return data
```